# checkbox become unchecked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/bRDgK/3/

In this situation I have a modal dialog with a checkbox. When the user click on the checkbox, a new modal dialog should appear and the checkbox should be checked. For some reasons the checkbox become unchecked. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why, but if I cancel event bubble (cancel event propagation for firefox) right before open the child modal - the checkbox stays checked as it should be.

Here is example (working only on IE because the inline onclick event and the `window.event` usage): http://jsfiddle.net/bRDgK/16/

Any idea how this solves the problem??

Answer (score 2):

Works fine with `onchange`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bRDgK/10/

**Additional findings**

Modal seems to be the problem. The modal is popping up and interfering with click event. Turning modal off all works fine cross browser. Suggest checking in  jQueryUI forum and/or reporting a bug

Comment: When i try your jsfiddle code, it's still unchecking the button. And i have tried with FF, IE and Chrome, no one seems to work

Comment: what browser, working good in FF. Is definitely a strange thing

Comment: This should work with click too and not only with change. In my code the onchange applies only when I am exit the checkbox (IE8). I need solution with onclick. I am using also with IE8.

Comment: see my additonal notes about modal

Comment: Please see my answer. If you have any explanation to this solution - I will be very glad :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for both firefox and IE8.

http://jsfiddle.net/executorjs/qevfZ/5/

I made a change on the doSomething function:

```
$(this).find("#ee").dialog("open");
```

Also changed the location of some html:

```
<div id="rrr">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dd" onclick="doSomething();" />
</div>
<div id="ee"></div>
```

Comment: you aren't using UI css so modal isn't activating. With no modal it works, along with fixing improper nesting which I did in first version

Comment: $(this).find("#ee") returns empty jquery object thus $(this).find("#ee").dialog("open"); does nothing.

Comment: Please see my answer. If you have any explanation to this solution - I will be very glad :)